# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method generate incomplete graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I cannot get my graphs to generate in my output. The first graph will generate incorrectly, but it shows up, unlike the others.

I've tried updating all my software and changing parts of my code, but it's not working for me. I'm not too sure how to change the subcode or if I should be changing any subcode.

I've read a couple of similar code errors but they are for arrays. I'm still very new at coding, so any help/tips will help me greatly!

```
Input

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(20, 10), sharex=False, sharey = False)
sb.despine(left=True)
sb.distplot(train['pickup_latitude'].values, label = 'pickup_latitude',color="g",bins = 100, ax=ax[0,0])
sb.distplot(train['dropoff_latitude'].values, label = 'dropoff_latitude',color="r",bins = 100, ax=ax[0,1])
sb.distplot(train['pickup_longitude'].values, label = 'pickup_longitude',color="g",bins = 100, ax=ax[1,0])
sb.distplot(train['dropoff_longitude'].values, label = 'dropoff_longitude',color="r",bins = 100, ax=ax[1,1])

Output
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
2 fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(20, 10), sharex=False, sharey = False)
3 sb.despine(left=True)
----> 4 sb.distplot(train['pickup_latitude'].values, label = 'pickup_latitude',color="g",bins = 100, ax=ax[0,0])
5 sb.distplot(train['dropoff_latitude'].values, label = 'dropoff_latitude',color="r",bins = 100, ax=ax[0,1])
6 sb.distplot(train['pickup_longitude'].values, label = 'pickup_longitude',color="g",bins = 100, ax=ax[1,0])

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in distplot(a, bins, hist, kde, rug, fit, hist_kws, kde_kws, rug_kws, fit_kws, color, vertical, norm_hist, axlabel, label, ax)
222 if kde:
223 kde_color = kde_kws.pop("color", color)
--> 224 kdeplot(a, vertical=vertical, ax=ax, color=kde_color, **kde_kws)
225 if kde_color != color:
226 kde_kws["color"] = kde_color

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in kdeplot(data, data2, shade, vertical, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, legend, cumulative, shade_lowest, cbar, cbar_ax, cbar_kws, ax, **kwargs)
655 ax = _univariate_kdeplot(data, shade, vertical, kernel, bw,
656 gridsize, cut, clip, legend, ax,
--> 657 cumulative=cumulative, **kwargs)
658
659 return ax

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in _univariate_kdeplot(data, shade, vertical, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, legend, ax, cumulative, **kwargs)
271 x, y = _statsmodels_univariate_kde(data, kernel, bw,
272 gridsize, cut, clip,
--> 273 cumulative=cumulative)
274 else:
275 # Fall back to scipy if missing statsmodels

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in _statsmodels_univariate_kde(data, kernel, bw, gridsize, cut, clip, cumulative)
343 fft = kernel == "gau"
344 kde = smnp.KDEUnivariate(data)
--> 345 kde.fit(kernel, bw, fft, gridsize=gridsize, cut=cut, clip=clip)
346 if cumulative:
347 grid, y = kde.support, kde.cdf

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.py in fit(self, kernel, bw, fft, weights, gridsize, adjust, cut, clip)
144 density, grid, bw = kdensityfft(endog, kernel=kernel, bw=bw,
145 adjust=adjust, weights=weights, gridsize=gridsize,
--> 146 clip=clip, cut=cut)
147 else:
148 density, grid, bw = kdensity(endog, kernel=kernel, bw=bw,

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.py in kdensityfft(X, kernel, bw, weights, gridsize, adjust, clip, cut, retgrid)
504 zstar = silverman_transform(bw, gridsize, RANGE)*y # 3.49 in Silverman
505 # 3.50 w Gaussian kernel
--> 506 f = revrt(zstar)
507 if retgrid:
508 return f, grid, bw

/Users/Kvera40/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kdetools.py in revrt(X, m)
18 if m is None:
19 m = len(X)
---> 20 y = X[:m/2+1] + np.r_[0,X[m/2+1:],0]*1j
21 return np.fft.irfft(y)*m
22

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method
```

I am expecting four graphs to generate in that are red and green for the longitude and latitude of the coordinates.

Comment: What is your code & what does the data you are trying to graph look like?